# Grouping 6-hour Data for Individual Days with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000,

I have data that contains a datetime and a value, say DateData and OtherData. Data is collected over time in five minute intervals, so for example, DateData is an ordered DateTime from 2/1/2016 to 2/24/2015, with a 5 minute gap between each new data point.

I am currently trying to average the data so that I can grab the average OtherData value every 6 hours, for each day individually. So far, I have come up with the following SQL that groups *all* the data into 6-hour intervals, so I end up with averages over all days, rather than individual.

```
SELECT
DATEPART(hour, DateData)/6,
AVG(OtherData) AS AvgData
FROM DATASITE
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, DateData)/6

--Result:
|Column1 | AvgData|
|0 | 11|
|1 | 12|
|2 | 13|
|3 | 14|
```

How would I change the above query to give averages for individual days, rather than all days combined?

Answer (score 0):

Add `DateData` in `Group by` to group the rows for each day

```
SELECT
DATEPART(hour, DateData)/6,
AVG(OtherData) AS AvgData
FROM DATASITE  
GROUP BY cast(DateData as date),
         DATEPART(hour, DateData)/6
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but grouping by an additional DATEPART() did. If I added DATEPART(day, datedata) and similarly for month it seemed to solve my problem. Is there any way I can preserver the datetime corresponding with the averages (2/2/2016, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(x.datedata AS DATETIME), 112) AS DATETIME) AS dt
,   DATEPART(hour, DateData)/6
,   AVG(OtherData) AS AvgData
FROM (
    select '20230730 15:00' as datedata
    , 1. as otherdata
    union all
    select '20230730 16:00' as datedata
    , 2. as otherdata
    union all
    select '20230730 17:00' as datedata
    , 2. as otherdata
    union all
    select '20230730 18:00' as datedata
    , 2. as otherdata
    union all
    select '20230731 00:00' as datedata
    , 2. as otherdata
    union all
    select '20230731 01:00' as datedata
    , 2. as otherdata
    ) x
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, DateData)/6
,   CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(x.datedata AS DATETIME), 112) AS DATETIME)
```

To remove the time parts, you can convert your date into varchar using style 112 (YYYYMMdd), and then convert it back to datetime.